# How to open two Chromium web pages in kiosk mode with "no-user-gesture-required" set, in a single bash script

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, chromium

I'm wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.  I have a raspberry pi that is set up to be used as a kiosk.  I have a dashboard web page that gets opened in kiosk mode via a service that calls a bash script. To play sound, I also need to open up a separate web page that is hidden behind the main dashboard. I know that to do this I need to set the autoplay policy as seen below.  No matter what I try, I can't get the sound web page open with the autoplay policy set from the same bash script that opens the dashboard.  If I enter 2 separate commands to open each page in the terminal, then it works.  What I have below opens both pages, but does not seem to set the autoplay policy like I want.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  The sound web page doesn't need to be opened in kiosk mode, as long as it is behind the dashboard page. Thank you!

Command in Bash script that opens both web pages but fails to let sound play.

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --new-window --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk 'www.myKioskDashboard.com' 'http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:8100/Sounds/TestView.html'
```

Commands that successfully open web pages individually with sound when entered in separate terminals (fails when both are sequentially in Bash script)

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --new-window --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk 'http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:8100/Sounds/TestView.html'
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --new-window --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk 'www.myKioskDashboard.com'
```

--UPDATE--

I think I may have realized the problem, but I am not sure how to resolve it. The image below shows when I enter the commands in two separate terminals.  Everything works like it should.  The web pages both open and there is sound. However, when I close the pages I noticed the error messages in the terminals.  Am I correct that this would prevent Bash from sequentially executing the commands if I just threw both of them in the same script?  Any ideas what are causing the errors?
[Terminal Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkC8y.png)

--UPDATE (again) --

It was suggested I use `&` after each command in my Bash script to make them run in the background.  When I executed the Bash script from terminal it worked!  One detail I left out, I am actually calling this script from a systemd service that executes on start up.  This unfortunately still does not work (it does when the script uses a command to open a single web page with no `&` at the end).  I didn't think this would be any different that calling the script from cmd.  I'm reading up on how systemd services work, but does anyone know why it might be failing? Thank you for the help thus far!

My service that calls the Bash script.

```
[Unit]
Description=Chromium Kiosk
Wants=graphical.target
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0.0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/kiosk.sh
Restart=on-abort
User=pi
Group=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

My Bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
xset s noblank
xset s off
xset -dpms
  
unclutter -idle 0.5 -root &

sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exit_type":"Crashed"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences

/usr/bin/chromium-browser --new-window --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk 'http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:8100/Sounds/TestView.html' &
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --new-window --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk 'www.myKioskDashboard.com' &
```

The issue:
If I don't use the service and execute the script from terminal `/bin/bash /home/pi/kiosk.sh` everything works fine.  Two browser windows are pulled up, with the dashboard in front, and the web page for sound hidden in back.  If I try to let the service call the script when it executes after startup, nothing happens.  When I try it with only one of those chromium browser call commands with no `&` at the end, the serves calls the script and it works fine.

--UPDATE--

I tried the suggestion about adding the path for all of the tool calls in the script. It still worked with the terminal call but not with the service. I then tried removing all of the tool calls except the two web browser calls from the script. Again, same thing. I took it a step further and only left one web browser call, same result. When I removed the `&` at the end then it worked fine with the service calling it, but I need the `&` to be able to open the two browsers.... I don't see how calling the script from the service should be any different than from the cmd?  I did notice that when the script is called from the cmd, these error messages pop up right before the web pages open.  Could this be causing issues with the service ?

[Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqZJu.png)

Comment: Why don't you 1) show the two commands that work in Terminal and 2) use those two commands in your script?

Comment: And if you post code, plesae [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it as code.

Comment: Try adding a space followed by `&` at the right end of each command to run in background.

Comment: That worked, thank you!  However, I think the `&` may be causing different problems that I wasn't anticipating, which I updated and elaborated on above.

Comment: Please show your complete `bash` script, and also explain what doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: I updated it :)

Comment: Go in your Terminal where the commands work, then get the full path to each tool and use that in your script. E.g. `type xset` might say `xset is /opt/local/X11/bin/xset` then use that full thing in your script. Likewise for `sed` and `unclutter`.

Comment: I did like you said but I got the same result.  It worked with the terminal call but not with the service.  I then tried removing all of the tool calls except the two web browser calls from the script.  Again, same thing.  I took it a step further and only left one web browser call, same result.  When I removed the `&` at the end then it worked fine with the service calling it, but I need the `&` to be able to open the two browsers....  I don't see how calling the script from the service should be any different than from the cmd?